# How to fix colors of bar graph

Tags: r

I want to produce a bar chart where the top bar is one color, and the bottom bars are a second color. For some reason my code keeps producing a graph where all the bars are the same color. How can I fix this?

```
counts <- structure(list(
`Residency Program` = c(4), 
`Coursework & Degree` =c(3), 
`Generalized Job Placement` =c(3), 
`Accelerated Program Duration (13 months)` =c(3), 
`Faculty and Staff Support` =c(3),
`Self-Efficacy in Teaching` =c(1),
`Perceived Impact on Students` =c(1),
`Stipend` =c(1),
`Resources` =c(1),
`Opportunities (generalized)` =c(1),
`MicroCredentials` =c(1),
`Hybrid (F2F and Online) Delivery Format` =c(1),
`Teaching Fellows Program` =c(1)
),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))

xFun <- function(x) x/1 + c(0.2, cumsum(x)[-length(x)])
counts <- counts[, order(colSums(counts))]
par(mar=c(5, 20, 4.1, 5))

byc <- barplot(as.matrix(counts), horiz=TRUE, 
col=c("dodgerblue4","slategray3","slategray3","slategray3",
                                                
"slategray3","slategray3","slategray3","slategray3",
                                               "slategray3","slategray3","slategray3","slategray3"),  # assign `byc`
           border=FALSE, las=1, xaxt='n', ylim = range(0,16.1),xlim = range(0,5) )
text(1.19, 0.75, "1")
text(1.19, 1.85, "1")
text(1.19, 3.1, "1")
text(1.19, 4.3, "1")
text(1.19, 5.5, "1")
text(1.19, 6.7, "1")
text(1.19, 7.9, "1")
text(1.19, 9.1, "1")
text(3.19, 10.3, "3")
text(3.19, 11.5, "3")
text(3.19, 12.7, "3")
text(3.19, 13.9, "3")
text(4.19, 15.1, "4")
```

Comment: I think this is because the way counts is structured. You have all your data in columns. I think you need to transpose the data to make each column a row. That seemed to change the color for me but it ended up messing up all the other formatting you did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may `unlist` your data, because so far you attempt to color the whole matrix (and actually use just one color). You can `rep`eat the duplicate colors, notice that the order is upside down because of `horiz=TRUE`.

For the labels you can easily use the object `byc` you've already exported, as well as the values adjusted by say `+.25`. This works because `text` also eats vectors as `x` and `y` arguments.

```
counts.plot <- unlist(counts)
counts.plot <- counts.plot[order(counts.plot)]

op <- par(mar=c(5, 20, 4.1, 5))  ## set par/store defaults
byc <- barplot(counts.plot, horiz=TRUE, 
               col=c(rep("slategray3", length(counts.plot) - 1), "dodgerblue4"),
               border=FALSE, las=1, xaxt='n', ylim = range(0, 16.1),
               xlim = range(0, 5))
text(counts.plot + .25, byc, labels=counts.plot)
par(op)  ## restore defaults
```

[image]